# full width background in table

Tags: html, css

I am making a newsletter with foundation. I need to get my background to go to full width, but at the moment the full width is defined in center:

[My Example](http://roulettesuite.com/test.html)

How can I make the background color go full width? Foundation has made a prewritten CSS, where the width should be defined:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%; }

#outlook a {
  padding: 0; }

body {
  width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  Margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
```

**This is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>A title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-emails.css" />

<style type="text/css">

.bgcolor {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.bgcolor--blue {
    background-color: #ccd8db;
}
.bgcolor--content--light {
    background-color: #ebe4cf;
}
.bgcolor--footer {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <style> -->
  <table class="body" data-made-with-foundation>
    <tr>
      <td class="float-center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>
          <table class="container" align="center">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <!-- Row 1 -->
                  <table class="row collapse" border="1px solid red">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <center>
                                  <a href="https://www.google.dk/"><img src="http://bbacher.weebly.com/uploads/8/4/6/2/8462405/6449752.jpg" alt="Logo" align="center" class="float-center"></a>
                                </center>
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!-- Row 2 -->
                  <table class="row collapse bgcolor--blue">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th class="small-12 large-12 columns">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <center>
                                  <a href="https://www.google.dk/"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/7a40daf7853d830815fb83f79752e94a/tumblr_mz2izkaidT1rfn9zxo4_500.png" alt="Fashion news" align="center" class="float-center"></a>
                                </center>
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you are able to edit html? If so, add a style="width: 100%;" on the img tag.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just tried that, but that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Table have padding and cellspacing by default. You'll need to manually remove these in order for your content to take up the full width and height of the element.

You'll need to do this on every table tag.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wb9qg34e/

With regards to the table not being responsive. You have set static widths to the table and there is a class pulling through that has a min width on

```
td.large-12 center, th.large-12 center {
    min-width: 532px;
}
```

If you remove the width from the table.container and add a new class like below, it should be fully responsive.

```
td.large-12 center, th.large-12 center {
    min-width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you again. But that does not make the background color go to full width.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you meant you want the image to take up all the space. I'm unsure as to which background color is not displaying "full width". Please give me the css class name that you're using in your example and I'll have another look.

Comment: Ah ok sorry, bad formulating from me. I made a Jsfiddle. This is working, but when you resize the screen, the logo is to the right, and I need to get that centered:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/4azpbdvx/)[/link]

In the bottom there is the custom css code

Comment: @MadsKristensen I've edited my answer for you. hope this helps as its the only reason I can see that your table isn't responsive. And if this is completely wrong from what you want, I'm really sorry :)

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. I am working up against a deadline, so I am totally pressured. Hm that is not working. I got the fluid code from the webpage [link](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/wrapper.html)[/link] . But i remove the column where the "BASIC" code is. Can that be it?

Comment: I found out that if you remove the `<center>` tag the image is getting responsive.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. You did say background-colour instead of background image though ;)